# Printer prints slides in the reverse order

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf

I never had problems on windows printing slides in the right order. In Ubuntu there is a problem:
I dont have adobe reader here. When I print some papers with the standard document viewer they will be printed in reversed order, so the last paper will get on the top (printed last).
I followed the instructions from Antonis answer ([Printers Always Print Pages In Reverse Order](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5780/printers-always-print-pages-in-reverse-order)) to solve this problem. 
But now when I want to print 4 slides on 1 paper, the slides on the paper itself will be printed in the reverse order... So it's 4 to 3, 2 to 1 from left to right, top to buttom.

A fix for some .pdfs is to use LibreOffice Drawer, because there it will be printed in the correct order. But on some .pdfs the formats will be messed up, because Libre Office can edit .pdfs...

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: In what order do you wish to print them?

Comment: 1 to 2, 3 to 4 from left to right top to buttom

Answer (score 0):

Using qpdfview (downloadable from the Ubuntu Siftware Centre), you can select the number of pages per sheet and then the page order from a selection.

[image]